# Need to find a word in a CSV file based off of conditional

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am truly stuck. My task here is to filter the dates of a 5000 record CSV to find a specific date range, order it in ascending order, and then take the fields of a different column which creates a sentence. I have been able to successfully sort for the dates and order them, but my problem now is that I don't know how to get the words that correspond with that row. Here is the code:

```
#/usr/bin/python3

import csv
import time


def finder():
    with open('sample_data.csv', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        r = [] # This will hold our ID numbers for rows
        c = [] # This will hold our initial dates that are filtered out from the main csv
        l = [] # This will hold our sorted dates from c
        w = [] # This will hold our words 
        sentence = '' #This will be our sentence

        # Filter out created_at dates we don't care about

        def filterDates():
            for row in reader:
                createdOn = float(row['created_at'])
                d = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(createdOn)) # Converts dates

                if d < '2014-06-22':
                    pass
                else:
                    c.append(d)

        filterDates()

        def sort(c):
            for i in c:
                if i > '2014-06-22' and i < '2014-07-22':
                    l.append(i)
                    l.sort(reverse=False)
                else:
                    pass

        sort(c)

        def findWords(l):
            for row in reader:
                words = row['word']
                for x in range(l):
                    print(words[0])

        findWords(l)

finder()
```

I know this code is probably sloppy and all over the place. I saw it as a challenge for a job and thought I could do it easily, but apparently my Python isn't quite up to snuff. I haven't used Python CSV before. I will say right off the bat that I no longer plan to apply for this job, but this will drive me crazy if I can't figure it out. I've already spent hours trying different things, my issue lies in how to take the rows that have the correct dates and get the words.

All suggestions and help is appreciated! For my own sanity, I need to figure this out.

Thanks,
RDD

Data Sample:

```
id  created_at  first_name  last_name   email   gender  company currency    word    drug_brand  drug_name   drug_company    pill_color  frequency   token   keywords
1   1309380645  Stephanie   Franklin    sfranklin0@sakura.ne.jp Female  Latz    IDR transitional    SUNLEYA Age minimizing sun care AVOBENZONE, OCTINOXATE, OCTISALATE, OXYBENZONE  C.F.E.B. Sisley Maroon  Yearly  ______T______h__e________ _______N__e__z_____p______e_____________d______i______a_____n__ _____h__i__v__e___-_____m___i____n__d__ _____________f ________c_______h__a__________s_.__ _Z________a_____l_____g________o__._   est risus auctor sed tristique in
2   1237178109  Michelle    Fowler  mfowler1@oracle.com Female  Skipstorm   EUR flexibility Medulla Arnica  Medulla Arnica  Uriel Pharmacy Inc. Yellow  Once    _____   morbi vestibulum velit id
3   1303585711  Betty   Barnes  bbarnes2@howstuffworks.com  Female  Skibox  IDR workforce   Rash Relief Zinc Oxide Dimethicone  Touchless Care Concepts LLC Purple  Monthly ___ ac est lacinia
4   1231175716  Jerry   Rogers  jrogers3@canalblog.com  Male    Cogibox IDR content-based   up and up acid controller complete  Famotidine, Calcium Carbonate, Magnesium Hydroxide  Target Corporation  Maroon  Daily   NIL augue a suscipit nulla elit
5   1236709011  Harry   Garrett hgarrett4@mlb.com   Male    Yotz    RUB coherent    Vistaril    HYDROXYZINE PAMOATE Pfizer Laboratories Div Pfizer Inc  Orange  Never   ï¿½_nb_l_ _u___ __olop __ __oq_l _n _unp_p__u_ _od___ po_sn__ op p_s '__l_ _u__s_d_p_ _n_____suo_ '____ __s _olop _nsd_ ___o_   morbi ut odio cras
6   1400030214  Lori    Martin  lmartin5@apache.org Female  Aivee   EUR software    Fluorouracil    Fluorouracil    Taro Pharmaceutical Industries Ltd. Pink    Daily   _   dui vel sem
7   1368791435  Joe Turner  jturner6@elpais.com Male    Mycat   IRR tangible    Sulfacetamide Sodium    Sulfacetamide Sodium    Paddock Laboratories, LLC   Aquamarine  Often   1;DROP TABLE users  nulla facilisi cras non velit
8   1394919241  Ruth    Bryant  rbryant7@dell.com   Female  Browsecat   IDR incremental Pollens - Trees, Mesquite, Prosopis juliflora   Mesquite, Prosopis juliflora    Jubilant HollisterStier LLC Aquamarine  Weekly  ___________ et magnis dis
9   1352948920  Cynthia Lopez   clopez8@gov.uk  Female  Twitterbeat USD Up-sized    Ideal Flawless  Octinoxate, Titanium Dioxide    Avon Products, Inc  Red Daily   (_ï¿½_ï¿½___ ___)   purus eu magna
10  1319910259  Phillip Ross    pross9@ehow.com Male    Buzzshare   VEF data-warehouse  Serotonin   Serotonin   BioActive Nutritional   Orange  Weekly  __  vel sem
```

Okay, so after some tweaking a great help from Westley White, I was able to get this functioning! I have it condensed into one nested function that is doing what it is supposed to! Here is the code:

```
#/usr/bin/python3

import csv
import time

def finder():

    with open('sample_data.csv', 'r', encoding='latin-1') as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        def dates(reader):
            # Set up variables
            date_range = []
            sentence = []

            # Initiate iteration through CSV
            for row in reader:
                createdOn = float(row['created_at'])
                words = str(row['word'])
                d = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(createdOn)) # Converts dates

                if d >= '2014-06-22' and d <= '2014-07-22':
                    date_range.append(d)

                date_range.sort()

                for word in words:
                    if d in date_range:
                        sentence.append(word)

            print(sentence)

        dates(reader)

finder()
```

There is only one problem left. When `sentence[]` appends, it appends each character one at a time. I don't know how to go about combining the letters into the words from the CSV column without combining them all together. Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: What's with the nested function definitions here? You don't need closures...

Comment: Is there a way to attach a file? I'd attach the whole CSV if possible. It's just sample data.
Also, what do you mean don't need closures? Sorry, my Python isn't great. Just getting back into it after a hiatus.

Comment: Honestly, just the header and the first couple of lines is all you need. With regard to closures, I am asking why you define functions inside a function, then simply call them inside that function.... it doesn't make any sense. You aren't going to be able to reuse those functions.

Comment: Added a data sample.

So should I have the functions defined inside the main function, then call them before I call finder() outside of the finder function?

Comment: What is "the main function"? You should define functions where they will be useful to you. *Calling* them inside `finder` seems reasonable. *Defining* them inside `finder` doesn't.

Comment: Ahhh, I follow now. I think I defined them inside `finder()` because I was defining the list variables inside, but I realize I could just put the variables outside of `finder()` and have them available globally.

Answer (score 2):

I dont know how the data is formatted, but here is my attempt.

import time

```
def finder(start_date='2014-06-22', end_date='2014-07-22'):
    """ 
    :param start_date: Starting date
    :param end_date: Ending date
    """

    def filterDates(reader):
        datelist = []
        for row in reader:
            created_on = float(row['created_at'])
            d = time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d', time.localtime(createdOn)) # Converts dates

            # Is between starting and ending dates
            if d >= start_date  and d <= end_date:
                # Going to use the created_on value so we dont have to reformat it again
                datelist.append(created_on)
        return datelist

    def findWords(reader, datelist):
        for row in reader:
            if  float(row['created_at']) in datelist:
                words = row['word']
                for word in words:      
                    print(word)

    with open('sample_data.csv', encoding="utf8") as csvfile:
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)

    dates = filterDates(reader)
    dates = dates.sort()
    findWords(reader, dates)     

finder('2014-06-22', '2014-07-22')
```

EDIT:
If you want to add each word to a list use this

Add this outside of the loop

```
sentence_list = []
```

change

```
words = row['word']
```

to

```
word = row['word']
```

then change

```
for word in words:      
    print(word)
```

to

```
sentence_list.append(word)
```

If you want to use a string add this outside of the loop

```
sentence = ""
```

Then when you print the word, just add it to the sentence

```
# adding a Word to the sentence
sentence = "{} {}".format(sentence, word)
```

and finally add this to the the bottom outside of the loop

```
print(sentence)
```

Comment: Hey man, this helped a ton! I used some of what you did here, but it also helped me re-examine the issue. I've updated the initial post with the new code and a question.

Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Check the updated answer. I thought there was multiple words in the row['word'] element. Since there is only a single word, Just add it to a string, or add it to a list to be used later.

Comment: Thanks, that helped a ton. Now I have to figure out why it's pulling words from outside of the date range...

I printed the date range just to be sure it's not adding random dates, and it's not, they are all correct, but when I run the code to find the words it's grabbing the correct words but also random words from totally random dates. Very strange.

Comment: Sometimes its better to print out the dates in a readable format so you can see if your data is correct. Write another script that will print out all of the data in a readable format and look for errors in the csv file itself. I dont see how a word could get past the date check if statement unless the add word is outside of the date check if statement